# GitHub post-receive hook not triggered on Windows

Tags: bash, git, jenkins, github, githooks

I'm trying to use a post-receive git-hook to automate the deploy of a simple maven project by triggering a Jenkins pipeline I set up. The source is hosted on a GitHub repo while Jenkins on a container running on my PC. So far, the hook is not triggered after I push to master branch.

Thing is if I try and run the script manually it just works! I also tried setting chmod +x with Git Bash (after all I'm on Windows) to the post-receive file, unfortunately without success: the hook still does not get triggered. What might be the issue?

I already tried looking for answers on similar topics here on stackoverflow, but nothing solved my issue. FYI, below the post-receive script (nothing fancy, as you can see):

```
#!/bin/bash
   
JENKINS_URL="http://localhost:8080"
JOB="deploy-to-slave-pipeline"
JENKINS_CREDENTIALS="theuser:11d422ee679503eeb328c5b1998327cc7f"

echo "Triggering Jenkins job..."
crumb=$(curl -u "$JENKINS_CREDENTIALS" -s '$JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
curl -u $JENKINS_CREDENTIALS -H "$crumb" -X POST "$JENKINS_URL/job/$JOB/build?delay=0sec"
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @bk2204 `post-receive` is a server-side hook. What I needed was a webhook, which can be set in the Settings/Webhook page of your GitHub repo. Just configure it as below where **Payload URL** is your Jenkins URL followed by `/github-webhook/`:

[image]

Then all you have to do is set your Jenkins job to get triggered by GitHub, by checking the related option on the **Build Triggers** section as below:

[image]

And then you're good to go! Also, if you're running your Jenkins instance locally, you could use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) to expose it and test your CI/CD pipeline!

[ref. [https://dzone.com/articles/adding-a-github-webhook-in-your-jenkins-pipeline]](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-a-github-webhook-in-your-jenkins-pipeline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `post-receive` hook is run on the server side, not on the client side.  That means that it's run at GitHub, assuming you're pushing to GitHub, ant not on your local machine.

Normally, you'd want a GitHub webhook to notify you of the push event, but you cannot use one here because the machine is running on localhost and such an event has to be able to on a public IP address since GitHub has to send an HTTP request to it.

Comment: Makes sense for it to be a server hook, but...I did some testing with a gitlab server container and the post-receive hook was working client-side, so I thought it would have been the same with Github.

Comment: This has nothing to do with GitHub or GitLab; this is the behavior of Git.  If you run a GitLab server container, then the hook will be run in that container, because that's the server to which you're pushing.

Comment: My bad, I got confused by my containers' names: the working post-receive hook I coded was in fact in the repo/.git directory stored on the gitlab server. Thank you for your time